# Evitar acceso a carpetas de archivos proyecto en PHP

Tags: php, apache, rutas

Hola me pueden ayudar con esta duda porfavor. Eh estado creando un proyecto sencillo en PHP y mysql casi lo termino. Ahora me surge como puedo hacer para que los visitantes no puedan ingresar a la carpeta padre es decir la que contiene los archivos. Por ejemplo si voy al navegador y pungo la siguiente ruta localhost/proyecto/templates/ me muestra el directorio de archivos que contiente esa carpeta en este caso el header y footer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como haría para evitar el acceso a dichas carpetas y mandarlas por ejemplo a la home. Quedo atento a las sugerencias gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Existen varías formas y todo depende de la configuración de tu servidor.

#### Opciones:

1. Poner un archivo `index.php` en cada directorio.
2. Poner un archivo `index.html` en cada directorio.
3. Crear/agregar al archivo `.htaccess` en la raiz del proyecto:

   ```
   Options -Indexes
   ```
4. Modificar tu `apache2.conf` y sacar `Indexes` de `Options`, ejemplo:

   ```
    <Directory /var/www/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      ...
    </Directory>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yo le hago así

Dentro de cada carpeta que esta a nivel de la raíz del proyecto incluyo un archivo denominado index.php y el codigo que añado es este:

```html
    <?php
/*
 FECHA: 2019-10-21
 AUTOR: xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
 */
$next="Location: ../../../index.php";  <-- revisa las ubicaciones de tus carpetas
header($next);
?>
```

Por no dejar reviso toda la estructura de archivos, y por donde se pueda colar uno añado ese archivo. En caso de que se pueda acceder como expones al inicio.  Esto no te permite retroceder o avanzar ("navegar" )sobre las carpetas del proyecto, te obliga a que te vayas a login.